# Can you detect if someone is using a Browser's "Find" function?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have found myself in a situation where I need to disable the browser's Find function... I am writing Javascript for a Qualtrics survey that is going to be used on Amazon's Mechanical Turk. So in my case, *if* a person is using the Find function in their browser, they are cheating. Since you really shouldn't be able to disable browser functionality (and to my knowledge, can't besides disabling Ctrl+F), is it possible to detect if an individual uses the Find functionality? That way I can warn them that this is cheating and possibly mark the data so the researchers are aware of that participant's attempt to cheat on the survey. I am unable to find any information on this and would like to know if I am on a fool's errand. If I can't nail this feature then the code I am writing will be useless as the validity of the data will be suspect.

Comment: if you can't stop the find feature, you must break it. you can use unicode chars that look like english letters to foil window.find(). you can also put transparent text between visible letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var isMac = navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC')>=0;
var ctrlKey = isMac ? "metaKey" : "ctrlKey"; // Cmd-F on Macs, Ctrl-F on others
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  if (evt.which == '70' && evt[ctrlKey]) {
    console.log("Hey! Cheater!");
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<input>
```

This will just log the Ctrl-F/Cmd-F keypresses. You can use `evt.preventDefault` if you want to disable it altogether. Unfortunately, there is no way to detect the use of menus: Edit -> Find will not trigger this code.

Comment: Hmm, if there is no way to detect the use of menu then I'm stuck changing all of the text to images. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is detecting the keyboard key event:

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (!(event.which == 70 && event.ctrlKey)) return true;
    alert("Ctrl-F pressed");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

It's worth noting that on Macs and some other keyboards, the `F` key might identify as a different keycode.

Comment: The problem here is that Edit -> Find would still work.

Comment: F is the same; but Ctrl is not used.

Comment: You could detect if they've clicked outside of the document altogether, and just give a warning or assumption of cheating. Or require full screen until complete and also disable ctrl + F

Comment: That's really helpful. I will check with the researchers to see if they are OK with asking the participants to do this.